# How can I git diff branches after rebasing on top of master

Tags: git, diff, rebase

Say I have a repo as:

```
A - B - C <- master
  \ D - E <- dev
```

Then, I create a new branch `feature` from `dev` and I rebase it on top of `master`

```
A - B - C <- master
 \        \ F - G <- feature 
  \ D - E <- dev
```

While doing the rebase, I need to merge manually a few files to get `F` and `G`.

Given this situation, when I finish the rebase, how can I see a diff of these changes I've made during the rebase?

More formally, I would like to get the diff between `F` and the resulting commit first after rebasing  `dev` on top of `master` with `-Xtheirs`. Same for `G` (with perhaps a slightly different command) and the second commit from this potential rebase.

Is there any way of doing this in a concise way without needing to actually rebase `dev` on top of master?

Comment: This sounds interesting but the question is unclear. What does this mean: "While doing the rebase, I need to merge manually a few files to get F and G." Why? Was there a merge conflict? And also, what does it have to do with the question? Exactly what do you want to diff? It's very confusing trying to figure out what the goal is. What is "doing this" in the last paragraph?

Comment: Doing this means, doing what I described in the second to last paragraph. When it comes to the merge conflict, it was just a simplification of the real case I have. In the real case you rebase on top of master and perhaps do an interactive rebase to modify a few files here and there. Then, I would like to have a way to enumerate these changes I've made in the interactive rebase after I made them. What you propose in your answer goes in the right direction, but I'd like to do automate the process of getting this diff in some way.

Comment: In the future, you might want to use `git rerere`, which records conflict resolution for use with later merges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### TL;DR

The simplest way to show the information you want is to diff the diffs.

##### The story

I tend to compare the contents of the commit themselves in situations like yours.

On the Bash prompt, the command

```
diff <(git show D) <(git show F)
```

will diff the diffs for you.

You'll get some spurious diffs: the sha1's of the commit and the files, the line numbers if those changed, and the context lines if those changed

So you need to look for lines that start with `< +`, `< -`, `> +` and `> -` to see the real differences between the change set in D and the change set in F.

Any changes you made manually for whatever reason, whether it's fixing a conflict or making further changes, will be shown in this diff.

##### Cleaner output

This variant of the diff command, proposed by OP @Lezkus in the comments, removes a lot of the noise in the diff output:

```
diff -I '@@[^@]*@@' -I '^index.*' -I 'commit.*' <(git show D) <(git show F)
```

##### The caveat

This is not exactly what you asked -- a script that cherry picks D onto C, diffs the results, and reverts it all would yield more precisely what you asked for -- but I think it's a decent compromise and it's super quick to run, requiring no setup or reverting of temporary operations.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! I ended up tweaking a bit the proposed command into `diff -I '@@[^@]*@@' -I '^index.*' -I 'commit.*' <(git show D) <(git show F)` to remove some unnecessary output, but this was exactly it. Thank you!

Comment: Nice variant, I'll edit it into my answer. I like how it removes a lot of the noise.